# Question allowed?

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-questions

I want to ask some questions not related directly to math problems, seeking for personal advices to be exact. So can you tell me where can I find answers for questions like "should I make a math blog?". Thank you all

Answer (score 10):

The question whether *you* should "make a math blog" depends a lot on *your* personal circumstances, competences, and priorities. It will be impossible to answer in a meaningful way for 'random strangers on the internet.' This question is thus not suitable for this site, and I'd say it just cannot be reasonably asked and answered on any internet site.

A question that may be more accessible is the abstract question of what are reasons for or against starting a math blog for somebody in some particular career situation that is described in some detail. This question is still somewhat borderline for this site, it not being a mathematical question, but it may be acceptable here. Indeed such a question was asked some time ago see: [Math blogs, pros and cons for writers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389565/math-blogs-pros-and-cons-for-writers)

The general answer is that a question about what *you should do* is almost never suited for an internet site. It will depend on *your* personal circumstances and what one should do is often intrinsically *opinion based.*

Questions that have a much better chance to be well-received are questions that ask for *points to consider* for somebody in a particular *situation that is described.*

Also note that questions about working and career development in academia are often better asked on the site [Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com); make sure to read their Help Center before asking though.

Comment: Another approach that might be better than posting this on Math.SE is to ask here on meta.Math.SE about the experience of those who wrote articles for the (now defunct) Math.SE blog (see [here](http://math.blogoverflow.com)).  This would likely be on-topic here, but so site specific as to have little application to your decision about a personal math blog.